# how to set bootstrap col-md-4 div to specific witdth and heigh with image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set 3 rows with `col-md-4` of same `div` width and append an image with class `img-responsive`.

What I am expecting was regardless of height and width of image it should fit proportionally to `div` width.

Suppose that image1.png, image2.png and image3.png have different proportions, eg. 250*210px, 290*380px, etc.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="image1.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="image2.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="image3.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to show portfolio on my website using pictures like a gallery, so I using col-md-4 to make rows, say like my images are image1(250*210), image2(290*380) etc.. but i want to fit them in 300*300 div element and they should be responsive

Comment: Improved question and code example

Comment: do you want to accomplish this with pure bootstrap classes or css is ok?

Comment: preferred bootstrap, so I can make them responsive

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `img-responsive` tag, you don't have to worry about the height and width of the image being more since it would adjust to the following,

```
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```